# FindFirstFile Windows8 error

Tags: c++

i'm trying to find all files on all drives, the OS is Windows 8

```
    std::string FolderName = "C:\\";
    FindAllFiles(FolderName);
...
void FindAllFiles(std::string FolderName)
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA FileData;
    HANDLE FirstFile = FindFirstFile(&FolderName[0], &FileData);
    if (FirstFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        std::cout << "Invalid handle value" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    while (FindNextFile(FirstFile, &FileData))
    {
        if (isalpha(FileData.cFileName[0]))
        {
            if (FileData.dwFileAttributes != FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
            {
                std::cout << FileData.cFileName << std::endl;
            }
            else
            {
                std::string NewPath = FolderName + FileData.cFileName;
                NewPath = NewPath + "\\*.*";
                    FindAllFiles(NewPath);
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

but always receive Invalid_handle_value error. What is the problem?

Comment: Since you are using narrow `std::string`, you should use `FileFirstFileA` as well as `WIN32_FIND_DATAA` and `FindNextFileA`.

Comment: The return value says it failed but not why.  `GetLastError()` will tell you why.

Comment: I change FindFirstFile to FindFirstFileA and WIN32_FIND_DATA to WIN32_FIND_DATAA and nothing

Comment: Change your initial filespec (one way or another) to `C:\\*.*`

Comment: @Lannser: Right, that was a comment because adding the `A` on the end won't solve the problem you are having, but it will save you headaches in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't call `GetLastError()`, which you should always do when a Windows function fails, but the most likely cause is that you failed to fill in `FileData` correctly before calling `FindFirstFile`.

Nearly all output buffers for use by Windows functions must be prepared:

- Populate the `dwSize` member using `sizeof` (this structure doesn't have this)
- Fill all other members with zero.

So try initializing the buffer with:

```
WIN32_FIND_DATAA FileData = {};
```

Comment: Interesting that [Microsoft's own "minimal use" example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418(v=vs.85).aspx) makes no such initialization.